# Sort a list alphabetically while ignoring case?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of artist names that I want to sort alphabetically, for example, a list like:

`val artists = listOf("Artist", "an Artist", "Cool Artist")`

Would become:

["an Artist", "Artist", "Cool Artist"]

To sort them, I use:

`artists.sortBy { it }`.

The problem is that kotlin seems to treat uppercase A and lowercase a as seperate characters [Possibly because of their ASCII order], leading to a sort order like this:

`[Artist, Cool Artist, an Artist]`

I could write something like:

`artists.sortBy { it.toUpperCase() }`

To have all the characters treated the same, but this is likely to cause problems in other languages.

Is there a way to make kotlin sort this alphabetically while ignoring whether the characters are lowercase or uppercase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found a better method for sorting in a case-insensitive order. You can use `list.sortWith {}` with a `compareBy()` call that uses `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`. Like this:

```
artists.sortWith(
    compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it.name })
)
```

If you just have a bunch of strings, you could do:

```
artists.sortWith(
    compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it })
)
```

This seems to sort properly, unlike `list.sortBy {}`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use .sort()

example:

```
val artists = listOf("Artist", "an Artist", "Cool Artist")
artists.sort()
```

Comment: Somehow I never realized that method existed, thanks! Is there a way to apply this method to a list of data classes that have a string in them?

Comment: In that case you were right to use the sortedBy method. Do sortedBy {it.artistName}

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!